# How can I have a dynamically allocated 2D array in C?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct, dynamic-memory-allocation

So I have a program with a struct

```
typedef struct s_struct {
    int rows;
    int cols;
    char* two_d; //This is supposed to be the 2D array
} *GRID;
```

I want to create a struck and dynamically allocate memory to it and then fill the 2D array but I don't know how. Here is what I have for the create(int prows, int pcols) function:

```
GRID grid = malloc(sizeof(struct s_struct));
grid ->rows = prows;
grid ->cols = pcols;
grid ->two_d = malloc(sizeof(char) * (rows*cols));
```

I don't understand how this creates a 2D array if it even does and how I can go about filling the array.

Comment: [This](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dynamically-allocate-2d-array-c/) may help.

Comment: There are many posts on SO on the subject. Checkout http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[c]+create+dynamic+2D+array.

Comment: fdo not typedef struct definitions.  It clutters the code, leads to misunderstandings, and clutters the compiler name space.   Then the tag name 's_struct' is not informative.  much better would be 'grid_t.  then use 'struct grid_t' in all future references.  Note: all caps 'GRID' is (by programing convention) reserved for macro/#define names.

Answer (score -1):

this line:

```
grid ->two_d = malloc(sizeof(char) * (rows*cols));
```

allocates a 'continuous in memory' grid/matrix
that can be referenced by:

```
grid[row_offset][cols_offset]
```

where the 'row_offset' can be 0...(row-1)

where the 'cols_offset' can be 0...(cols-1)

```
note: 'sizeof(char)' is always 1, 
so including that phrase
in the malloc parameter just clutters the code 
because '(1*something)' is always 'something' 
as the 1 has no effect.
```

suggest: remove the 'sizeof(char)' from the malloc parameter

Comment: It cannot be accessed by `grid[row_offset][cols_offset]`